# TOC nested incorrectly in PDF viewer's side pane

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

The following is a minimal example of my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newenvironment{qu}[1][]{\par\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{ #1}}{\par}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{a section}
\begin{qu}[foo]\end{qu}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{another section}
\begin{qu}[bar]\end{qu}
\end{document}
```

The table of contents generated by latex looks correct, sort of like this:

```
Contents
a section
  foo
another section
  bar
```

When I compile this (twice) with pdflatex, it also generates a table of contents that my pdf viewer (the Evince application on linux) knows about and displays in a side pane. That side pane has the wrong hierarchical structure:

```
a section
  1. foo
    another section
      2. bar
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Without `bookmark` or `hyperref` package there should be no ToC Pane(l) at all.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks, that was a mistake. I've fixed the code in the statement of the question. I'm invoking hyperref.

Comment: Using `bookmark` package, the pane should be correct, however, but the main cause is the missing `\phantomsection` before your manual `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{another section}` -- there's no information that the bookmark level has jumped back to `section` otherwise. `ToC` is not `bookmark` ;-)

Comment: The cleanest solution is `\usepackage{bookmark}`.

Comment: Yay, that works. Thanks! If you want to make that an answer, I could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a contentsline manually with some entry higher than the current bookmark level does not reset the bookmark level, i.e. `section` level in ToC will not be shifted back to section level of bookmarks.

The `bookmark` package takes care of this, otherwise `hyperref` and manual `\phantomsection` usages are another, but worse solution, in my point of view.

Another advantage of `bookmark` package is that the outline (the bookmarks panel) is correct after one compilation run already.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[open=true]{bookmark}

\newenvironment{qu}[1][]{\par\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{ #1}}{\par}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{a section}
\begin{qu}[foo]

\end{qu}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{another section}
\begin{qu}[bar]\end{qu}

\end{document}
```